# Extend private classes in a dynamic assembly

Tags: .net, reflection.emit

I’m developing a framework which allows to define what I call a presentation for an arbitrary object – you may understand such presentations as an aspect of an object. For example: objects of a certain application should be visualized by a render engine. Instead of extending the type of the object itself, you provide a presentation supplied by a service (the render engine) that reads data from the object (and may write data to in the context of other presentations).

The framework expect some interfaces to be implemented by application types in order to use the functionality. However, if the application does not provide implementations for those interfaces, the framework is automatically subclassing the type and adds default implementations for those interfaces, like this:

The framework (Managed C++):

```
namespace Spoc::Claire
{
  public interface class IEntity
  {
    void DoSomething() ;
  } ;
}
```

Here's a simple application (C#):

```
namespace Spoc.Samples
{
  class Hello
  {
    public Hello()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello world") ;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Entity.New(typeof(Hello)) ; // creates the "Hello" object within the context of the framework
    }
  }
}
```

What the framework creates by reflection within a dynamic assembly is:

```
namespace Internal
{
  class Hello : Spoc.Samples.Hello, Spoc.Claire.IEntity
  {
    public void Hello()
    {
      // call the base class constructor
    }
    public void DoSomething()
    {
      // default implementation for IEntity
    }
  }
}
```

This object is returned to the application and because of inheriting from the given type, it can be used without any restrictions.

So what's the problem? All runs fine if the application defines their types as "public". If not, like in the above described example, I'll get an TypeLoadException from the TypeBuilder::CreateType() Method saying "Access denied for type Spoc.Samples.Hello".

At the first look one may say: well, you're trying to extend a private class outside its assembly. My argument is: yes, I do derive from a private class but within a dynamic assembly, that is by the way flagged with "RunAndCollect", so it can never be saved and thus, types cannot be used elsewhere but in the current instance of the AppDomain. Theroetically I do not violate the private principle since the new type remains private and, frankly said, in a much more strict sense: private to the current instance of teh AppDomain.

I've played around with the friend assembly paradigm but apart from the fact that friendships do violate a strictly object-oriented design, I do hard to specify my dynamic assembly as a friend. I also found the ReflectionPermission attribute but ceased with that undergoing too.

Is anyone out there who can give me some advice?

PS: And yes, I can go a pragmatic way by saying, that every object trying to utilize the framework need to be public. Unfortunately I see a framework as a vehicle that should not necessarily limit down the possibilities of the underlying language not should it put implicit knowlegde.

Comment: I finally got it working with:
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("<my dynamic assembly>")]
set within the AssemblyInfo.cs of the example mentioned above.

However, I'm still in the opinion that it should work without the necessity to place any helper in the applications using the framework. I know it's esotheric since the application needs to use the factory pattern provided by the framework anyway. True, but with strong names, setting the attribute becomes more coplicated because the public key of the internal assembly is required .

Comment: You seem to be confused, `internal` types have nothing to do with AppDomains, they can't be used from different assemblies, which is exactly what you're trying to do here. And since it seems you found your solution, you should post that as an answer, when you can.

Comment: Well, I don't see it as a solution rather a cirumvention that interimly work for me. Regarding to "my obviuos confusion" - I do unterstand your point. However, a "RunAndCollect" assembly is not what I call ordinary assembly - such an assembly is bound to the life cycle of the AppDomain instance in which it was created. And so, I don't see a violation of the internal visibility when using internal classes in the context of such an assembly...  an this is: I think I'm not confused.

Comment: Furthermore I want to add some other findings. With a RefectionPermissionFlag::MemberAccess set for the current AppDomain instance and assumning the AppDomain instance is running fully trusted, one can invoke/set even private members/types within trusted assemblies. It simply doesn't work for dynamic assemblies - this is from MSDN, just don't have the link at hand.

Comment: Have you looked at [ImpromptuInterface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/). You might be able to do this with proxies instead. You have a default implementation implemented in one class, and then you subclass an ImpromptuForwarder to on failure to invoke the default object and then let impromptu emit the Interface proxy to your forwarder. Then nothing is sub-classing internals or private, just invoking, which is way easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I was advised to do so, I finally place my findings as an answer.

With a RefectionPermissionFlag::MemberAccess set for the AppDomain instance hosting the dynamic assembly and providing enough evidence for the assembly in order to have it run fully trusted, the the dynamic assembly should beable to invoke/set even private members/types within trusted assemblies. However it doesn't and this is clearly stated by MicroSoft - RefectionPermissionFlag::MemberAccess isn't functioning for dynamic assemblies.

What works is: [assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("")] set within the AssemblyInfo.cs of the assembly, whose private types/methods should be accessed from within a dynamic assembly. The bitter thing is, that you can't do that for assemblies from third parties.